# Como escapar código HTML dentro de um atributo do tipo data-text?

Tags: html, visual-studio

Escrevi o seguinte código:

```
<label class="form-input">
                <i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></i>
                <input class="password-mask input-popover"
                       type="password"
                       autocomplete="off"
                       id="NewPassword"
                       maxlength="16"
                       name="NewPassword"
                       required
                       onchange="VerifyInput('NewPassword', 'newPassword-text'); this.setCustomValidity('');"
                       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, preencha este campo.')"
                       onkeyup="CalculeStrength('NewPassword', 'strengt-bar', 'strengt-label')"
                       title=" "
                       data-toggle="popover"
                       data-html="true"
                       data-content="<div><p>Digite ao menos uma letra</p></div>"
                       data-container="body"
                       data-trigger="focus" />
                <span id="newPassword-text" class="label">Nova senha</span>
                <span class="underline"></span>
            </label>
```

O problema é que dentro do atributo 'data-content' preciso inserir um código em HTML que depois será formatado via CSS.

Estou usando visual Studio e ele não está escapando as '/'.

Como posso fazer para escapar as '/'?

Comment: Como vc pretende usar esse HTML? Vai inserir na página?

Comment: Trata-se do componente popove do bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers. Ele deve apresentar um balão contendo as instruções do formato que o usuário deve cadastrar a senha.

Comment: Sei. Ele tá exibindo o HTML como se fosse um texto comum, não é isso?

Comment: exatamente, ele exibe o texto contendo as tag's. Pode inclusive notar no trecho de código que eu colei que o compilador sequer reconhece o input como uma tag HTML.

Comment: É que a "amostra de código" daqui só destaca a tag HTML se tiver tudo na mesma linha. No seu caso aí, vc quebrou linhas para cada atributo, provavelmente para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Bom, pelo teste que fiz aqui, o HTML do popover funciona normal com o HTML, inclusive troquei cores da div etc e funcionou.